# Linux Hostapd registers as WEP, but I want WPA2-PSK

Tags: linux, linux-networking, wifi, hostapd

as usual to respect the community, I have traversed a bajillion articles and re-read the manual and still can't seem to get past this issue.

I'm trying to create an access point in Linux(linaro on a dragonboard 410C) with hostapd to register as WPA2-PSK, but when I do a wifi scan, it keeps showing WEP.

My config looks like the following

```
ssid=TestAccessPoint
interface=wlan0
hw_mode=g
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=1
wpa=2
wpa_passphrase=omgiloveunicorn5
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
```

I fire off the hostapd, the daemon appears to launch successfully, but it keeps reporting as WEP instead of WPA2-PSK. If I try to manually create the connection, nothing happens.

When I also try to connect to the access point from any device, it reports the following error

```
wlan0: STA blah blah blah: authenticated
wlan0: STA blah blah blah: No WPA/RSN IE in association request
```

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

As I am also toying around with `hostapd` I have tested your config.

Starting from my (working) config I narrowed it down to two changes:

- add a `channel`
- for `auth_algs` use value 3 (instead of 1)

Thereafter I can connect from another client to this AP and airport on MacOS reports the AP as using WPA2:

```
$ airport -s | grep Katzenklo | awk '{print $1, $7}'
Katzenklo WPA2(PSK/AES/AES)
```

Employed versions:

- Debian 8, kernel 3.16.0-4-amd64
- hostapd 1:2.3-1+deb8u3

Config which works:

```
channel=6 # added
ssid=Katzenklo
interface=wlan0
hw_mode=g
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=3 # instead of 1
wpa=2
wpa_passphrase=omgiloveunicorn5
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. My android phone is still reporting WEP and discovering others as actual WPA2-PSK. I'm wondering if there is some external variable factor or configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that the Dragonboard 410C hardware is simply not capable of being a WPA2-PSK access point host. It can act as a client and the original configuration works with different hardware.

Thanks @Zoliton for the time! I really appreciate it.